# Can i write formatted math equation in my website

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to write math equations

can i handle this with (HTMl - Javascript)

is that possible in web development ??

i want the equation to look like this

[image]

Comment: Do you want to just be able to write (or assemble) the equation or do you want to be able to evaluate it as well?

Comment: Everything is possible, but do you want only to display this or you want to calculate?

Comment: I just want to write it  @ScottMarcus

Comment: I don't want to calculate any thing @MiloshN.

Comment: Well, I think your best bet would be to place graphics of all the possible operators, variables, and numbers on the page and then use drag and drop to allow someone to "assemble" the equations.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you but is there any source to help me doing this ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: I think you could do it with a calculator-like keyboard or you can let the user write in a specific syntax and then, when done writing, you show the result in that form. This website handle this problem very well https://www.geogebra.org/cas